# string modification taking input using get

Tags: c, gets

I am trying to modify value of one string using other .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
char ch[10],s[3];
int c;
fgets(ch,10,stdin);
fgets(s,2,stdin);
c=(int)s[1];
ch[3]+=c;//s[1];
printf("%c\n",s[1]);
printf("%s",ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is blank for s[1] and ch remains unchanged . However the program works fine if i remove the second gets and use a constant in place of c. 
I would like to know the my error as well as the best simple approach for string manipulation .

EDIT : changed s[2] to s[3] , still same result

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What are the inputs?

Comment: What output do you expect ?

Comment: Totally guessing: are you entering 10 char string for the first fgets?

Comment: print it hex it'll give you a more clear idea about it %p,s[1],

Comment: @SouravGhosh input are 2 strings

Comment: @LPs  i am entering 6 characters

Comment: @Sorcrer i get (nil) ..

Comment: @Sorcrer Passing data having wrong type to `printf()` invokes *undefined behavior*. Try `printf("%x\n",(unsigned int)(unsigned char)s[1]);`

Comment: @Code_reaper You increased the actual buffer size, but failed to increase the buffer size to tell to `fgets()`. This is why using magic numbers isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second `fgets()` read something (1 character), a terminating null character will be written to `s[1]`.

Bits in terminating null character are all zero, and it means that the value of `s[1]` will become `0`.

Adding zero means almost nothing.

Comment: but even when i declare s[3] and use s[1] ... still no change in output !

Comment: It doesn't matter. `fgets(s,2,stdin);` reads 1-char + *nul-terminator* (`0`) into `s`, `c=(int)s[1];` is `c=0`. `ch[3]+=c;` adds `0` to `ch[3]` (so it is still `ch[3]`) (remember `fgets` also read the `'\n'` as part of each line and includes that in `s`, so hitting the `enter` key with no input leaves `'\n',0` in `s`)

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a combination of issues. The first being if you are reading `fgets(s,2,stdin);` you get a maximum of `1` character in `s` plus the *nul-terminating* character. If you then take `c=(int)s[1];` you are reading the second character of `s` into `c`. The second character of `s` will *always* be either `'\n'` (`0xa` hex, `10` decimal) if 1 character is entered or `0` (the *nul-terminating* char).

You run into your next problem with `ch[3]+=c;`. The result of which must fall within the printable range of characters. (see: [**asciitable.com**](http://www.asciitable.com/) ). That means if `ch` contains `AAAA`, the first character of `s` must have an ASCII value of `61` or less to remain in the printable character range.

Take the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char ch[10] = "",
          s[3]  = "";
    int c = 0;

    printf (" first input : ");
    fgets (ch, 10, stdin);
    printf (" second input: ");
    fgets (s, 3, stdin);
    printf ("\n you entered:\n first : %s second: %s\n", ch, s);

    c = s[0];
    ch[3] += c;

    printf(" s[1] : %c\n",s[0]);
    printf(" ch   : %s\n",ch);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use**

```
$ /bin/fgetsbasic
 first input : HAHA
 second input: !

 you entered:
 first : HAHA
 second: !

 s[1] : !
 ch   : HAHb
```

Anything with an ASCII value greater than `61` will cause you to fill the 4th character of `ch` with a non-printable value. (this changes depending on what the 4th char in `ch` originally is)